# enum switch-case style dynamic_cast

Tags: oop, c++11, design-patterns, dynamic-cast

Is there any design pattern which uses `dynamic_cast` the way like use a `switch-case` statement?

In practice, when I use `dynamic_cast` like this:

```
  if (auto *type1 = dynamic_cast<Foo *>(&base)) {

  } else if (auto *type2 = dynamic_cast<Bar *>(&base)) {

  } else {
    throw WtfException();
  }
```

I think there's two problems with this:

1. if I got types other than two, the if-else statement may effect the performance(compared with  switch-case statement of which most implementations are used hash map)
2. It's make me uncomfortable to state a `else` statement, since the compiler knows the type, the `else` statement acts very similar to the `default` statement in an enum switch-case statement, that is, if every case is listed, the `default case` is useless, and if not every case is listed while no `default case` listed, the compiler will warn me. I think this rule also fits to the `dynamic_cast` cases.

So is there any design pattern which can make the use of `dynamic_cast` as if using the enum switch-case style?

Comment: I suppose it's the case where the visitor pattern would be useful.

Comment: This doesn't fit the switch-case pattern because a derived class can be dynamically casted to multiple types, so the order of tests is important.

Comment: @RaymondChen good point